# Log4j MongoDB stuck in timeout after 30000ms

Tags: java, mongodb, log4j, log4j2, mongodb-atlas

I have configured Log4j2 to write the logs to my Mongo Atlas cluster (4.4.8).

The configuration seems ok (I use the connection string given by Atlas), and the logs (console) say that the connection to the MongoDB is ok, database retrieved correctly and collection retrived correctly.

But then, when it tries to write a log to the DB, it times out after 30000ms saying:

`Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[]`

I also can see several messages saying:

```
INFO  org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Cluster description not yet available. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
```

What I don't understand is that, using the very same driver, same connection string, all the operations I perform on this same MongoDB managing the connection myself (I have a MongoDBService class where I build the Mongo Connection etc...normal stuff) work with no problem, so it leads me to thing that it is Log4j that handles the connection to MongoDB in a bad way...

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I have the exat same issue even on my local mongo docker container. Did you resolve the issue?

Comment: Hi @hosseinshemshadi. No, nobody seems to be able to help...I don't know what happens, and it seems we are very few willing to use log4j into mongo db unfortunately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the problem in my configurations. Maybe it works for you too.
I was used to have multiple appenders in root logger. So mongodb was trying to log something like: "hey, I'm going to log" after initializing the RollingFileAppender but before the mongodbAppender. You can see it in below:

```
    Root:
  level: info
  AppenderRef:
    - ref: ConsoleAppender
    - ref: RollingFileAppender
    - ref: MongoAppender
```

Just by changing the mongo appender's logger everything worked for me.

```
logger:
  - name: com.sinansoft
    level: info
    additivity: false
    AppenderRef:
      - ref: MongoAppender

Root:
  level: info
  AppenderRef:
    - ref: ConsoleAppender
    - ref: RollingFileAppender
```

Let me know if you want more configuration details in this case.

Comment: You solved it!! It worked for me too! So the problem was in the order of how it initializes the loggers it seems.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue for multiple cloud hosted clusters from multiple different node.js instances, docker containers, and kubernetes clusters. After a lot of troubleshooting and reading, I had discovered that my personal firewall was blocking it. I simply allowed port 27017 and everything worked.